# Add html to wp_login_form

Tags: login

Inside a template there's

```
<?php wp_login_form( array( 'echo' => true ) ); ?>
```

Source code

```
<p class="login-remember">
<label>
<input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"> Remember Me
</label>
</p>
```

I'd like to add a span tag after `Remember me`

```
Remember Me <span class="custom-styled-checkbox"></span>
```

I tried to add some html to the label but that didn't worked:

```
    $args = array(                  
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me <span class="custom-styled-checkbox"></span>' ),
        );
   wp_login_form( $args );
```

Neither did something simple as this

```
function custom_checkbox_form($output) {
    $search  = array('<p class="login-remember"><label>','</label></p>');
    $replace = array('<p class="login-remember"><label>', '<span class="custom-styled-checkbox"></span></label></p>'); 

    return str_replace( $search, $replace, $output );
}   
add_filter( 'login_head', 'custom_checkbox_form', 99, 1 );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `label_remember` argument is for changing the text only; HTML will be escaped, so that won't work here.

Instead, the HTML for the login form can be parsed and modified before it is output:

```
// Get the HTML for the login form
$login_form = wp_login_form( [ 'echo' => false ] );

// Create an instance of DOMDocument 
$dom = new \DOMDocument();

// Populate $dom with our login form, making sure to handle UTF-8, otherwise
// problems will occur with UTF-8 characters.
$dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding( $login_form, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8' ) );

// Create an instance of DOMXpath and get the <p class="login-remember"> node
$xpath = new \DOMXpath( $dom );
$remember = $xpath->query( '//p[@class="login-remember"]' );

// Iterate over the $remember node...
foreach ( $remember as $container ) {
    // Create the <span> element
    $checkbox_span = $dom->createElement( 'span' );

    // Create the class attribute
    $checkbox_span_attr = $dom->createAttribute( 'class' );
    // Set the value of the class attribute
    $checkbox_span_attr->value = 'custom-styled-checkbox';

    // Add class="custom-styled-checkbox" to the <span> element
    $checkbox_span->appendChild( $checkbox_span_attr );

    // Append the completed <span class="custom-styled-checkbox"></span> element
    // to <p class="login-remember"><label>
    //$container->childNodes[0]->appendChild( $checkbox_span ); // Fails on PHP < 5.6.3?
    $container->childNodes->item(0)->appendChild( $checkbox_span );
}

// Save the updated HTML to $login_form and output it.
$login_form = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $login_form;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The code returns an error. Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: I'm guessing you're running a [PHP version prior to 5.6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845819/fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-domnodelist-as-array). I have updated the code accordingly. Keep me posted if it's still not working.

Comment: It's working! Thank you. It was indeed this line `$container->childNodes[0]->appendChild( $checkbox_span );`